# What is "Vet." or "Veter." an abbreviation for in these references?

Tags: abbreviations

Gibbon references "Panegyric Vet." or "Panegyric Veter." a few times in DandF's notes, e.g. `the orator Eumenius (Panegyric Veter. viii 6`, or `Panegyr. Vet. v 18.`

The Panegyric is referring to the *Panegyrici Latini*, but I can't figure out what the Vet. is. In doing some searching, I've found references in other books that are similar, e.g. `Panegyrici Veter. Gallicani` or `Panegyrici Latini Vet. 2 (12).5.1-2`. But in no case have I seen it spelled out, and I haven't found any reference in any general entries on the *Panegyrici Latini* to it or anything like it.

What does the Vet./Veter. stand for?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Salve, and welcome to the site!

Apparently, the [**Panegyrici Veteres**](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1148591281) is an [alternative name](https://books.google.cl/books/about/XII_panegyrici_latini_The_collection_kno.html?id=2nvrMgEACAAJ&redir_esc=y) for the [**XII Panegyrici Latini**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Panegyrici_Latini). Currently, only the 9th is attributed to [Eumenius](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eumenius#Panegyric). In the past, eight of them —from the 5th to the 12th— (and even all twelve) were attributed to him.

Here, **veteres** is the plural form of **[vetus](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=Perseus%3Atext%3A1999.04.0059%3Aentry%3Dvetus)**, *old*.

Comment: Unrelated to the content: It seems that you started your answer with "Hello" or some such greeting and the system removed that word automatically without telling you. If you greet in Latin or not at all, the system will never know... (And +1 for the content.)

Comment: @JoonasIlmavirta, hahaha, thank you

Comment: The same quirk seems to have had an effect on [your newest answer](https://latin.stackexchange.com/a/14596/79) too.

Comment: @JoonasIlmavirta  will I ever learn?

Comment: I'm told people learn with repetition, and you have done that. :P